# how do you select only the entire string in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried looking up this questions but they were for the entire line.

My question is for example `let url = "https://robohash.org/hello.png?set=set4";`

here, is there any shortcut to select only the url or basically anything enclosed between "". Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible without an extension. You can download [Quick and Simple Text Selection](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbankier.vscode-quick-select), the use `ctrl+k "` shortcut.

If you're familiar with Vim, you can use the [vim](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) extension, and then click `v i "` to enter `visual` mode, and choose everything between double quotes

---

For the sake of completeness, `vscode` also includes a `smart select` option, which has the keyboard shortcuts <s>`ctrl+shift+right_arrow` and `ctrl+shift+left_arrow`</s> (The shortcut has been changed to `alt+shift+left/right_arrow`). The problem with it is it doesn't specifically select everything between double quotes, and in the case of a URL, it doesn't simply work as intended. If it's only a simple string, it would also select the double quotes in addition to the string between them

Comment: okay i will check the extension out, thank you! marking answer as correct

Comment: This type of selection can be achieved by multiple ways. 

- ⇧ ⌥ ⌘  ← / →

- ⇧ ⌘      ← / →

Answer (score 11):

I just found a magical shortcut :)

For expand selection we can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>⇨</kbd>

See [HERE](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_shrinkexpand-selection) for more details and examples.

Comment: Just like what the accepted answer states, this hotkey does not work in all cases, for example when the string is a URL and there are `/` characters in the string, the `Expand Selection` hotkey does not know how to properly expand the selection. This answer should not exist

Comment: @omgirok I tested with URL and UNC path strings and it worked fine. I think the answer is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

For mac, the "expand selection" shortcut is <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>▶</kbd>

Click anywhere in the link and expand the selection twice, that should do it.

Answer (score -1):

There is actually another [expansion](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=letrieu.expand-region) called expand_region with the ability to
`expand_region` and `undo_expand_region`. The default keybindings are `ctrl+w / shift+ctrl+w` .

I find this one to be more convenient.
It stops before and after `"`  and it will work for the url-fetch scenario.
What it doesn't do is to stop at a complete line (with and without indentation) which `smart select` seems to do. There are probably more differences that I don't know about.

Update: You have to press multiple times to expand further. For the example line in the original post this means 3 times.
`ctrl+w, ctrl+w, ctrl+w`

```
let url = "https://robo[cursor-here]hash.org/hello.png?set=set4";
1. https://robohash.org/hello.png?set
2. https://robohash.org/hello.png?set=set4
3. "https://robohash.org/hello.png?set=set4"
```

Comment: You probably got down-voted because you are using the `expand-region` extension but didn't mention that!

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! I've had it for so long that I forgot that it was an expansion. Updated the answer